# Are UK pensioners living in Canada covered for medical issues in EEU countries?

Tags: health

Is a dual national UK/Canada resident in Canada covered in EEU countries if they are receiving a UK pension?

Comment: UK *residents* are covered on a par with locals if they have a European Health Insurance Card through the NHS but I don't think this applies to non-residents. Unless you want to settle somewhere else in the EU, you will therefore have to see if there is some reciprocity agreement with the Canadian healthcare system (which I don't know at all, do you have health insurance in Canada?), irrespective of your link to the UK.

Comment: I assume you're talking about provincial insurance. From travel experience it is very limited outside Canada, so I wouldn't count on it.